# Symfony access_control for admin not working

Tags: symfony, access-control

My code is security

```
security:
  access_control:
    - { path: '^/(%app.locales%)/profile/messages', roles: [ROLE_ADMIN]}

  role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER]
```

User has role ROLE_ADMIN, but get access denied. If i change code:

```
security:
  access_control:
    - { path: '^/(%app.locales%)/profile/messages', roles: [ROLE_USER]}

  role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER]
```

All it's OK. I have access. Where i have error?

Comment: I can't make out what is causing your problem, but here is some general advice to help you debug: Check your log file for any authentication-related errors. You could also look into the failing request in the web profiler toolbar's Security section. It will should tell you why access was denied. Please expand your question if you find anything useful.

Comment: Thank you. And I'm sorry, today I went to work, without changing anything in the code since yesterday, and it all worked. I do not know the reason, I cleaned the cache yesterday ...

Comment: No need to apologise. Good to hear it works now. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I changed the role through the database. In order for this to apply, it was necessary to log out and log in.